# How does this USART level shifter circuit work?

Tags: uart, voltage-divider, level-shifting

I'd like to ask how this circuit works:

[image: Circuit]

I understand how it works in principle, but not technically. It's a USART voltage level shifter. It's supposed to divide 5V to 3.3V by a resistor divider, in the direction from microcontroller (on the left ATMEGA328), to RFmodule which works with 3.3V. But in opposite direction, a transistor has been used which I do not understand. Arrow above R8 resistor indicates 5V.

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/296879/logic-level-converter-using-transistors/297092#297092

Answer (score 1):

Consider what happens when the TX on the 3V side goes high and low.

If its High, Vbe < 0V (emitter is at 3V and base is at the voltage of the 4k7 and 10k divider, ~2.2V), so no Base current, and the transistor is off. R8 pulls the other side to 5V.

When its Low, Vbe ~=0.7V, the transistor is on, and the TX is able to pull the other side low.

Comment: Vbe is never 3.3V. The base is held at 2.245V when Uart_TX is high, and the base is at approximately 0.7V when UART_TX is low. T2 is simply a non-inverting buffer and level translator.

Comment: @JackCreasey -- thanks for pointing that out. I wrote that in a rush. I'll add it to the answer.